# Django internationalization on admin

Tags: django, internationalization, django-admin

I'm writing an app where the final administrator might not speak English, so it would be nice to present the admin interface in a non-English language.

I've read the i18n documentation but it doesn't mention how to change the text of the "add" buttons and titles of the pages (in the admin interface). How can I accomplish this or what docs are the ones that I need to read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely, [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/translation/) are the best docs. If you want admin site in specific language - just set proper `LANGUAGE_CODE` in settings.